# how can I calculate $\lim\limits_{z \to 0} {\exp(-1/z^4)}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

> $\lim\limits_{z \to 0} {\exp(-1/z^4)}$

It may be easy but i'm not sure it's correct.
the answer that i got was 0.

Comment: Yes, the answer is zero, do you recognize why?

Comment: i would like if you explain to me,

Comment: Use polar form $z=re^{i\theta}$ and plug in

Comment: First of all thank you !
it would be very helpful for me if you can write the full steps.
i'm new in calculating complex limits.

Comment: What happens when you substitute polar form? The above hint is very useful. Give it a try first

Comment: I got it! thank you very much !!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is not 0. This limit is not well defined. To prove it one must show that it takes different values for different sequences converging to zero. Take, say
$$\{z_n\} = e^{i\pi/4}n^{-1},$$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. The other sequence you can find easily.

Actually, this limit will take all complex values except at most one, but this is another story.

Comment: You seem to be mistaking $\exp(1/z)$ and $\exp(-1/z)$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri How are those functions different in that regard? Both have essential singularities at the origin.

Comment: You are correct. My bad.

Comment: "this limit will take all complex values except at most one," No, the limit doesn't exist. How can something that doesn't exist  take on values?

Comment: @zhw. I mean that for every complex value, except maybe one there will be a sequence $\{z_n\}$ converging to zero, such that $\exp(-1/z_n^4)$ will converge to that value.